# Programacion-Codigos While

Tags: c++, while

Hola soy muy principiante a la hora de programar y estoy en una duda que me vuelve loco, quisiera saber si en bucle (utilizando while) pueda guardar datos y despues esos datos sumarlo para que salga un nuevo valor.

Un ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo:

> El programa se trata de una caja registradora.
> Cree un bucle para que cada vez q pregunte se repita el ciclo.
> Una vez seleccionado el producto de compra, pongo en otra linea si el cliente cuanta cantidad se llevara ahora le pongo la cantida le doy enter y sale el total de pagar con la cantidad, en la otra linea me aparece si el cliente pidio otro producto, le doy si.Entonces vuelve a repetir ingreso el producto, le ingreso la cantidad y despues me sale el total de pagar con la cantidad.

Es decir

- Primer producto= 12*2=24
- Segundo Producto=30*2=60

Ahora teniendo eso necesito sumar esas dos variables que darian los 84, pero no puedo porque lo puse como un ciclo y solo muestra el 60, que hago??? la verdad es que nose si me pude explicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    cout<<"---------------Caja Registradora---------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"----------El cliente escojio algun producto---------- "<<endl;
    cin>>producto;
    while(producto=='S')
    {
    cout<< "1. Teclados Meetion: $12.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "2. Mouse Asus: $30.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "3. Auriculares Sonny: $19.99"<<endl;
    cout<< "4. Cables Usb de 2 metros: $3.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "5. Docena de discos en Blanco: $5.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "6. Gabinetes Speedmind: $50.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "7. Reguladores: $25.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "8. Monitores Quasad: $75.00"<<endl;
    cout<< "9. Mando de ps4: $29.99"<<endl;
    cout<< "10.Baterias Doble A: $5.00"<<endl;
    cin>>productos;
    {
        arr=local[productos-1];
    }
    clientes=clientes+arr;
    cout<<"¿Cuanta cantidad eligio el cliente?"<<endl;
    cin>>cantidad;
    tcantidad=arr*cantidad;
    cout<<"Total por cantidad= $"<<tcantidad<<endl;
    cout<<"El cliente pidio otro producto? "<<endl;
    cin>>producto;
    }
    subtotal=tcantidad+tcantidad;
    cout<<"Subtotal: "<<subtotal<<endl;
    ventas=clientes+ventas;
    cout<<"Corte: "<<ventas<<endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Una variable, puede contener un solo valor.. no? si vos queres guardar mas valores, o necesitas mas variables, o una estructura que guarde muchos valores, como si fueran muchas variables ;)

Comment: No tiene ninguna relación con programación asíncrona, así que quité esa etiqueta.

Answer (score 1):

Intentaré responder tú duda, espero no revolverte más.

El problema lo tienes en la línea:

```
tcantidad=arr*cantidad;
```

Estas obteniendo el valor actual del producto que quieres, sin embargo, sobre escribes la variable, si quieres adicionarlo para que se sumen el valor anterior y el nuevo, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
tcantidad= tcantidad + arr*cantidad;
```

De esta manera, le dices al programa que utilice la variable global tcantidad que ya tiene guardado algo en otros ciclos.
Espero que esto resuelve tú duda